# Neighborhoods of the identity in diffeomorphism groups

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Finite dimensional Lie groups have the nice property that if $V$ is a small neighborhood of the identity, and $U \subset V$ another neighborhood, then $V$ is covered by $U^k$ (the set of all products of $k$ elements of $U$) for some $k$.  This follows from the fact that V is relatively compact.

Does the same property hold for small enough neighborhoods of the identity in an infinite dimensional Lie group?  My favorite example is the group of compactly supported diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- is it known whether it has this property?

Remark: I'm pretty sure this property is not equivalent to local compactness, so the fact that $Diff_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not locally compact doesn't give an answer.

Comment: You're right about the fact that it does not force locally compact, even under suitable completeness conditions. For instance, the group $G=Homeo(S^1)$ satisfies: for every neighborhood $U$ of the identity, there exists $k$ such that $U^k=G$. But this cannot carry over diffeomorphism groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What helps a little is that for any (second countable connected) smooth manifold $M$, the connected component $Diff_c(M)_0$ of the group $Diff_c(M)$ is perfect (Epstein) and simple (Thurston). On the other hand, $\exp: \mathfrak X_c(M)\to Diff_c(M)$ is far from being locally surjective. Grabowski has shown, that for $\dim(M)\ge 2$ there exists a smooth curve in $Diff_c(M)$ starting at the identity such that the element of these curve (sauf the identity) form a free generating system of a free subgroup of $Diff_c(M)$ such that no element $\ne 1$ of this free subgroup embeds into a flow. This free subgroup of uncountably many generators  is contractible to 1 (slide each generator to 1 along the curve).

## EDIT

Some references:

- (1) Martins Bruveris, François-Xavier Vialard: On Completeness of Groups of Diffeomorphisms.  J. Eur. Math. Soc. 19 (2017), no. 5, pp. 1507–1544, doi:[10.4171/JEMS/698](https://doi.org/10.4171/JEMS/698), [arXiv:1403.2089](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2089).
- (2) S. Haller and T. Rybicki and J. Teichmann: Smooth perfectness for the group of diffeomorphisms. J. Geom. Mech. 5(2013), 281–294. doi:[10.3934/jgm.2013.5.281](https://doi.org/10.3934/jgm.2013.5.281), [arXiv:math/0409605](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409605).
- (3) David Mumford, Peter W. Michor: On Euler's equation and `EPDiff'. Journal of Geometric Mechanics 5, 3 (2013), 319-344, doi:[10.3934/jgm.2013.5.xx](https://doi.org/10.3934/jgm.2013.5.319), [arXiv:1209.6576](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6576),
  [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/eulerlink.pdf).
- (4)  M. Bauer, J. Escher and B. Kolev: Local and Global Well-posedness of the fractional order EPDiff equation on $\mathbb{R}^d$, Journal of Differential Equations 258 (Mar 2015), no. 6, 2010-2053, doi:[10.1016/j.jde.2014.11.021](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2014.11.021), [arXiv:1411.4081](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4081).

In [3], Thm 2, see (1) and (4) for more information, it is shown that the right invariant Sobolev metric of integral order $s>\frac{n+3}2$ is geodesically complete on $Diff_{H^\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ and the corresponding Riemannian exponential mapping is a diffeomorphism from a suitable $H^s$-ball in $\mathfrak X_{H^\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ into the group.
This easily implies the result that the OP asked, but only for $H^s$-balls; thus for the Sobolev completion, the topological group (with smooth right translations)
$$Diff_{H^s}(\mathbb R^n) = \{Id + f: f\in H^s(\mathbb R^n)^n, \det(Id + df) > 0\}.$$
Namely, consider any $H^s$-ball $V$ of radius $r$, Then any open neighborhood in $V$ contains a $H^s$-ball of radius $\epsilon>0$. Papers (1) and (4) show that one can connect any diffeomorphism $\phi\in V$ to the identity by a geodesic $c$ of length $<r$. Cut this geodesic in $\frac{\epsilon}2$-pieces $\{c(t): t_i\le t\le t_{i+1}\}$, $0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\dots<t_N=r$.
Then $c_1(t)=\{c(t): t_1\le t\le r\}. c(t_1)^{-1}$ has length $r-t_1$, and finally
$\phi=c(r)= c_N(r).c_{N-1}(t_{N-1}).\dots.c_1(t_2).c(t_1)$.

Moreover, for $Diff_{H^\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, where $H^\infty$ is the intersection of all Sobolev spaces, a Frechet space, the result also holds, since each neighborhood of the identity in  $Diff_{H^\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ contains a $H^k$-neigbourhood for sufficiently large  but finite $k$, and we can apply the result with the $H^k$-metric.

But $Diff_c(\mathbb R^n)$ has many more open neighborhoods, and for these nothing follows.

Comment: Thanks! although I'm not sure how simplicity might help here (?)  Here's a different way to think of the same kind of question with a more metric formulation: put your favorite (complete, left-invariant) metric on Diff_c(M).  Is there k so that every diffeomorphism in the epsilon ball about the identity is the product of k elements in the epsilon/2 ball?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this new argument seems to work whenever there is a right-invariant metric such that the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism, provided that $V$ is small enough to be a diffeomorphic image of an open ball under exp.  I gather this is not known for $Diff_c(R^n)$ but is for Diff(S^1) with the $H^k$ metrics, when k is at least 1?

Comment: You also need that the right invariant metric is geodesically complete (the geodesic equation is globally well-posed).

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on Peter Michor's answer, I want to say that we can however use the exponential map.

*Is it true* that the image of the exponential map is locally dense near the origin? If so, let us take open neighbourhoods $U\subset V$ of the identity such that $\overline{\exp(Vect_c(M))}\supset \overline{V}$. Given any $g\in V$, we can find $h_0\in U$ arbitrarily close to $id$ so that $gh_0^{-1}=f$ is the time $1$ map of a flow $\{f_t\}_{t\in[0,1]}$. Let $k=k(f)$ be the minimum integer such that $f_{1/k}$ belongs to $U$. Then $g$ is the product of $k+1$ diffeomorphisms in $U$:
$$g=f_{1/k}\circ\cdots\circ f_{1/k}\circ h_0.$$

*The problem* here is that $\overline{U}$ is not compact so it doesn't seem clear that we can have a uniform bound on the choice of $k$ (though we still have some freedom in the choice of $h_0$).

**Edit** Katie Mann is true that the image of the exponential map can happen to be not dense about the origin. There is one case for which I know that my question has a negative answer and this is a result by Nancy Kopell in Commuting diffeomorphisms, *Global Analysis, Proc. Symmpos. Pure Math.* vol **XIV** (1968), 165-184 ([AMS page](https://www.ams.org/books/pspum/014/) - subscription required), see also Yoccoz, Petits diviseurs en dimension 1 *Astérisque* **231**, SMF (1995) ([Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/issues/AST_1995__231_/)):

Kopell's Theorem states that the $C^1$ centralizer is trivial for an open dense set of $C^1$ circle diffeomorphisms. In particular there exists an open dense set of diffeomorphisms of the circle which are not the time 1 map of a flow.

Comment: I think whether the image of exp is dense in a neighborhood of the origin is not known, and probably difficult.  For example, the paper "Local Density of diffeomorphisms with large centralizers" (Bonatti, Crovisier, Vago and Wilkinson, https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4319 ) shows that for a surface S, there is an open set in Diff^1(S) with a dense subset of diffeomorphisms that are the time 1 map of a flow, and state the higher-dimensional analog as a question.  I have no idea what is known in the smooth (rather than C^1) case.